# Choose random number of random items without replacement from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Assuming that I have a normal distribution of `N(5,1)`, and numpy array `np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`.

I'm trying to choose random number from the array without replacement, and the number of the random number should be sampled from the normal distribution.

For example, this is what I got.

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# choose 3 random numbers
n = 3

how_many = (1 * rng.standard_normal(n) + 5)
sample = rng.choice(arr, n, replace=False)

chosen = []
for s, h in zip(sample, how_many):
  chosen += [s] * int(h)

print(chosen)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Apparently, I found it really slow. Any ideas on how to make it fast?

Comment: It's Python, how fast do you expect it to run?

Comment: Note that this is ***not*** an appropriate use of the normal distribution.  Normals have support on the range [-infinity, infinity], so while you're several standard deviations above zero you're eventually going to get a negative value if you run it long enough or are unlucky.  You should use an integer distribution such as binomial, geometric, or Poisson, to name a few.